# Transforming an `Option[Tuple]` in a scalaz `\/`

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am trying to create a connection from an `Option[Tuple]`, and return
the result in a disjunction, but my code looks a bit weird:

```
  def ssh(config: GushConfig): \/[Throwable, Client] = {
    val params = for {
      host <- config.mysqlHost
      port <- config.mysqlPort
      user <- config.mysqlUser
      password <- config.mysqlPassword
      sshAddress <- config.sshTunnelAddress
      sshTunnelUser <- config.sshTunnelUser
    } yield (host, port, user, password, sshAddress, sshTunnelUser)

    params match {
      case Some((host, port, user, password, sshAddress, sshTunnelUser)) ⇒
        Try({
          // Do stuff that can fail and throw exceptions

          new Client("127.0.0.1", lport, user, password)
        }) match {
          case Success(v) ⇒ v.right
          case Failure(t) ⇒ t.left
        }
      case None ⇒
        new Exception("Not enough parameters to initialize a ssh client").left
    }
  }
```

I first need to pattern match my first `Option` to check that I have
all required options, and then if I do, try to connect inside a `Try`
and then convert the result of the try into a disjunction.

Is there a nicer way to do this transformation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to convert them both to the same type - you can use `.toRightDisjunction` on the `Option`, and you can do the `Try` thing using `scala.util.control.Exception` instead:

```
import scala.util.control.Exception._

for {
  params_ ← params.toRightDisjunction(
    new Exception("Not enough parameters to initialize a ssh client"))
  (host, port, user, password, sshAddress, sshTunnelUser) = params_
  v ← catching(classOf[Exception]) either functionThatCouldThrow() disjunction
} yield v
```

You could also do the initial `Option` thing using `.sequence` rather than an explicit `for`/`yield` (this might require shapeless-scalaz):

```
params = (config.mysqlHost, config.mysqlPort, ...).sequence
```

Answer (score 3):

scalaz.std package contains the

```
object option extends OptionInstances with OptionFunctions {
  object optionSyntax extends scalaz.syntax.std.ToOptionOps with scalaz.syntax.std.ToOptionIdOps
}
```

The operations Scalaz add to `scala.Option` are defined in `OptionInstances` (the typeclasses) and `OptionsFunctions`. `OptionFunctions` contains the following methods:

```
  final def toRight[A, E](oa: Option[A])(e: => E): E \/ A = oa match {
    case Some(a) => \/-(a)
    case None    => -\/(e)
  }

  final def toLeft[A, B](oa: Option[A])(b: => B): A \/ B = oa match {
    case Some(a) => -\/(a)
    case None    => \/-(b)
  }
```

The syntax and the implicit conversion are provided in the `scalaz.syntax` package, and in particular `OptionOps` is Scalaz "Rich Option". The `ToOptionOps` contains an implicit conversion from `Option => OptionOps`

If you import correctly optionSyntax, you can write the following

```
import scalaz.std.option.optionSyntax._
val disjunction = params.\/>(new Exception("Not enough parameters to initialize a ssh client"))
```

And then you can map/flatMap from there